# How to use haskell stack 1.2, nix, and ghcjs

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, nix, ghcjs

When I try to build this [repo](https://github.com/mckeankylej/ghcjs-typeahead) with the latest version of stack:

```
λ ~/repos/ghcjs-typeahead/src/Typeahead/ master* stack --version                      ~/repos/ghcjs-typeahead/src/Typeahead
Version 1.2.0 x86_64
```

I get this error:

```
λ ~/repos/ghcjs-typeahead/src/Typeahead/ master* stack build                          ~/repos/ghcjs-typeahead/src/Typeahead
Only GHC is supported by now by stack --nix
```

This is because my stack.yaml looks like this:

```
resolver: nightly-2016-08-26
compiler: ghcjs-0.2.0.820160826_ghc-8.0.1
compiler-check: match-exact
setup-info:
  ghcjs:
    source:
      ghcjs-0.2.0.820160826_ghc-8.0.1:
        url: "http://tolysz.org/ghcjs/ghc-8.0-2016-08-26-nightly-2016-08-26-820160826.tar.gz"
        sha1: "2ecd8523cafe22b3033726363b4acc5356117970"
nix:
  enable: true
  shell-file: shell.nix
packages:
- location: '.'
- location:
    git:  https://github.com/ryantrinkle/reflex.git
    commit: a63aba90bdea5ae5b3e1506d468613bdfedcdfa3
  extra-dep: true
- location:
    git: https://github.com/ryantrinkle/reflex-dom.git
    commit: ed3b790f81f8396324fc9a3495de9c911119facc
  extra-dep: true
extra-deps:
- ghcjs-dom-0.2.4.0
- ref-tf-0.4.0.1
- zenc-0.1.1
```

It is very unfortunate that they removed support for the method I was using is there any other way to use stack, nix, and ghcjs? Do I have to go back to using cabal?

Comment: Under the "try-reflex" environment included (and described) in the https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-platform repository, I was able to compile and link the project you link to using just ghcjs.  The "try-reflex" command is, I believe, a wrapper around nix.  So, while not "stack, nix, and ghcjs", this "nix and ghcjs" combo does not include cabal and might be a solution for you.

Comment: Yea. I convinced my boss to let me just use cabal but previously I had to use stack. Sad they removed the feature though it worked flawlessly.